# Hypothetical Questions Regarding Keyloggers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, element, keylogger

Recently, a lot of people in my house have been going on my computer when I wasn't there and I want to make sure that I know what they have been on, for the sake of privacy. I had the idea of making a keylogger that I could use to see what they have been doing on my computer. The keylogger itself (as in a program that records key strokes) I could make, but I have another idea in mind that I'm not sure is possible.

My idea is basically, like a keylogger, something that compiles a list, or log, of the activities of the user, but to a greater extent. I was wondering if it would be possible to document the actions of the user to the extent that every element of the screen they clicked on would be documented. In a web browser, I'm sure there would be a way to do this as all of the information (ids) of the elements of the page can be collected by inspecting the elements (looking at the code). As for general use of the computer, I'm not so sure.

In simpler terms, I want to make a program that would record the users actions in a log as shown below.

**14:17:** User clicked Windows Start Button

**14:17:** User searched for 'Chrome' in search engine

**14:17:** User opened 'Chrome'

**14:18:** User clicked URL address bar

**14:18:** User searched for 'stackoverflow.com'

**14:18:** User clicked 'Login' button on 'stackoverflow.com'

I'm not an expert by any means and only have a school-level knowledge of programming, but I want to know if it would be possible to create something like this. I want the program to be able to collect all of these major actions so that I can compile them within a hidden text document. I'm not sure if these elements could be identified by a program but if anyone has any idea how I would do something like this or indeed if I could do something like this, by all means, message me on here. I would be EXTREMELY grateful!

P.S - This is my first post on here, go easy on me, aha.

Comment: Is it possible? Of course! How do you implement it?...That is way too broad of a question. Stack Overflow is for if you have a *specific* programming problem or bug. See the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for details of how to ask a good question.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to stop people going on your PC - screen saver with password for example.

Comment: Note that the [tag:visual-studio] tag description says *"DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."* Please [edit] your question to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

With .NET code you will definitely be able to get window positions of other applications (for example google chrome). 
For example with the following library: https://github.com/DataDink/WindowScrape

Furthermore you should be able to track keyboard inputs and mouse-clicks of the user on the desktop (which position he clicked on). I think the evualuation of the mouse-clicks will be up to you ("user clicked on url-bar in chrome").

Just a personal hint from me: Doing something like that without informing the person using the PC you will be heavily punished. Think about it twice.